# How to add hints in a query using declare_rewrite_equivalence in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, psql

I am using the following command for test purpose. I am trying to use `optimizer_features_enable = 11.2.0.4`:

```
BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE.declare_rewrite_equivalence (
     name             => 'test_rewrite',
     source_stmt      => q'[SELECT * FROM danilo.teste where id = 10]',
     destination_stmt => q'[SELECT /*+ opt_param('optimizer_features_enable','11.2.0.4') */ * FROM danilo.teste where id+0 = 10]',
     validate         => FALSE,
     rewrite_mode     => 'TEXT_MATCH');
END;
/
```

When I run `SELECT /*+ opt_param('optimizer_features_enable','11.2.0.4') */ * FROM danilo.teste where id+0 = 10` it works fine

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  3rk4g55nv4w11, child number 0
-------------------------------------
SELECT /*+ opt_param('optimizer_features_enable','11.2.0.4') */ * FROM
danilo.teste where id+0 = 10

Plan hash value: 1912010946

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name  | E-Rows |E-Bytes| Cost (%CPU)| E-Time   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |       |        |       |     3 (100)|          |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TESTE |      1 |     3 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - SEL$1 / TESTE@SEL$1

Outline Data
-------------

  /*+
      BEGIN_OUTLINE_DATA
      IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS
      OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('11.2.0.4') <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<MY HINT
      DB_VERSION('12.2.0.1')
      ALL_ROWS
      OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$1")
      FULL(@"SEL$1" "TESTE"@"SEL$1")
      END_OUTLINE_DATA
  */

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("ID"+0=10)

Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):
-----------------------------------------------------------

   1 - "ID"[NUMBER,22]

Note
-----
   - Warning: basic plan statistics not available. These are only collected when:
       * hint 'gather_plan_statistics' is used for the statement or
       * parameter 'statistics_level' is set to 'ALL', at session or system level


49 rows selected.
```

But `SELECT * FROM danilo.teste where id = 10` does not add the hint, only the predicate `id+0`

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  2864wwtfadurg, child number 0
-------------------------------------
SELECT * FROM danilo.teste where id = 10

Plan hash value: 1912010946

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name  | E-Rows |E-Bytes| Cost (%CPU)| E-Time   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |       |        |       |     3 (100)|          |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TESTE |      1 |     3 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - SEL$FE5C51BE / TESTE@SEL$45646F97

Outline Data
-------------

  /*+
      BEGIN_OUTLINE_DATA
      IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS
      OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('12.2.0.1') <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<NO CHANGE
      DB_VERSION('12.2.0.1')
      ALL_ROWS
      OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$FE5C51BE")
      MERGE(@"SEL$45646F97" >"SEL$1")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$1")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$45646F97")
      FULL(@"SEL$FE5C51BE" "TESTE"@"SEL$45646F97")
      END_OUTLINE_DATA
  */

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("ID"+0=10) <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<PREDICATE OF MY destination_stmt

Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):
-----------------------------------------------------------

   1 - "ID"[NUMBER,22]
```

Why the hint does not work?